# Are there any caveats to signing an unsigned third party assembly myself?

Tags: .net-4.0, c++-cli, .net-assembly

I have a third party assembly that I need to reference from a signed assembly that we build. I know how to do this, however, what kind of potential implications might I expect from signing their assembly ourselves?

Here is some additional information about the scenario:

- The assembly is used to talk to a third party service which we do not build ourselves.
- At this point, the unsigned assembly is only used to get information which is converted to a new format which has been developed in house, so we don't wish to pay support to the third party in order to obtained a signed assembly since we are phasing it out.
- This third party assembly is merely an assembly for .NET applications to interface with the third party API which was not written in .NET (I think it was written in C/C++).

My main concern is that if I sign the assembly, it will not be able to interface with the service/have issues utilizing the native assemblies which are installed by the third party, though I have never had to do this before so I don't know if there is anything else I should be concerned about when signing third party assemblies. Any assistance in clearing this up is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: We only reference the third party assembly in a very specific scenario, so I am trying to set up a test environment. This is time consuming however, so I was hoping there might be a clear cut "no this won't work" at least to save time. I am also not just asking this for my use-case here, but it would be nice to know of any "gotchas" that might be present when signing a third party assembly that I would need to watch out for in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it all ended up working when I signed our third-party assembly. However, there are some things when signing a third-party assembly you need to take into account:

- Any native calls in the assembly will probably fail
- Modifying third-party assemblies may be a violation of your software agreement

These are the only gotchas I've been told about so far (assuming you do properly sign the assembly in the first place).

Also as an FYI, In my case it would have been better to remove the unsigned DLL from the project reference and use Assembly.Load or Assembly.LoadFile to load the unsigned assembly from the signed one.